# Fetching query in PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have this php code,

```
$result = $Db->query("SELECT DISTINCT matkul_mahasiswa.nim, matkul_mahasiswa.kode_matkul, 
                      nilai.nim, nilai.kode_matkul, nilai.nilai, nilai.kode_ta, nilai.status_nl
                      FROM matkul_mahasiswa 
                      JOIN nilai
                        ON matkul_mahasiswa.nim = nilai.nim AND matkul_mahasiswa.kode_matkul = nilai.kode_matkul
                     WHERE nilai.kode_matkul = '$kdmk' AND nilai.status_nl = '1' AND nilai.kode_ta = '$kdta'");
```

then I tried to fetch it with PDO, and echo the result

```
$data = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo $data['nim']; 
echo $data['nilai'];
```

but nothing, nothing show up.
I tried the query on phpmyadmin, and it works fine

So, what's wrong ? what do I miss here ?

thanks b4.

Comment: Var dump the whole  $data variable. You may have different field names than you expect. Honestly, you are the only one who can answer this question by debugging your own code...

Comment: yeah, i did that and the result is "bool(false)", so that means the query didn't work.. but it work on phpmyadmin. 
I actually wanted to do full outer join, but it was error so I modified it and finally work then when I put the query on php this happens...

Comment: Surprise, surprise - you can check with pdo if there are any sql related errors...

Comment: Set PDO to throw exceptions and then you'll know what the error is ~ `$Db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)`. You'll should also display all errors while developing ~ `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'On');`

Comment: Also, you should be using a prepared statement and binding `$kdmk` and `$kdta`

Comment: I believe the error is probably due to the repeated column name `nim` in the `SELECT` clause from `matkul_mahasiswa.nim` and `nilai.nim`. You should provide an alias for at least one of those

Comment: In fact, they appear to be references to each other in the two tables so there's absolutely no need to select both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one (I changed a bit your approach and added prepared statements cause you are just asking for SQL injection).

```
$stmt= $Db->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT matkul_mahasiswa.nim AS matkul_mahasiswa_nim, matkul_mahasiswa.kode_matkul, nilai.kode_matkul, nilai.nilai, nilai.kode_ta, nilai.status_nl FROM matkul_mahasiswa JOIN nilai ON matkul_mahasiswa.nim = nilai.nim AND matkul_mahasiswa.kode_matkul = nilai.kode_matkul WHERE nilai.kode_matkul = :kdmk AND nilai.status_nl = '1' AND nilai.kode_ta = :kdta");
$stmt->bindValue(':kdmk', $kdmk);    
$stmt->bindValue(':kdta', $kdta);
$stmt->execute();

while($row = $stmt->fetch()) 
{
    $out[] = $row;
}

return $out;
```

Comment: Could have more easily used `$out = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`

Comment: I know :) I prefer it this way cause it gives a template to make some operations on outcome before creating output . Your way is of course also valid.

Comment: Fix the duplicate `nim` result columns and you'll have a working answer here :)

Comment: I gave `nim` 2 different aliases cause not sure if it's a duplicate or just same column name in 2 tables with different context.

Comment: Well, on second glance they appear to be the same value (foreign key references in the two tables) so there's really no need to select from both as they'll be the same

Comment: Finally worked, the prepared statement really help a lot.
I used this for the output, easier this way. `$out = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`
Thanks guys.